# Retrieve XML nodes not working with new file

Tags: excel, xml, vba, nodes

I have a code that succesfully retrieves the node values from XML files but I now have a file where it doesn`t work anymore, eventhough it is the same build up. Is it possible that it has something to do with the "_" sign in the XML? I already checked if I made a typo.

Snapshot of the XML where is works:
[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Automatically generated XML file -->
<ADEL:Report xmlns:ADEL="http://XMLSchema/MT/Generic/ADEL/v2.1.11"> 
  <Header>
    <Title>Lot Report</Title>
    <MachineID>7</MachineID>
    <MachineCustomerName>AT</MachineCustomerName>
    <MachineType>X</MachineType>
    <SoftwareRelease>at5.0.0.c</SoftwareRelease>
    <CreatedBy></CreatedBy>
    <CreateTime>2020-03-03T11:32:27.726447+01:00</CreateTime>
    <MachineHostDeltaTime>0</MachineHostDeltaTime>
    <Comment>
    <elt></elt>
    </Comment>
    <DocumentId>20303-47</DocumentId>
    <DocumentType>ADEL</DocumentType>
    <DocumentTypeVersion>v2.1.11</DocumentTypeVersion>
    <CategoryList></CategoryList>
  </Header>
</ADEL:Report>
```

Snapshot of the XML file where it doesn`t work:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Automatically generated XML file -->
<ADEL:Definitions xmlns:ADEL="http://XMLSchema/MT/TWIN/ADEL/v6.2.1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://XMLSchema/MT/TWIN/ADEL/v6.2.1 ADEL.xsd">
<RecipeCollection>
<UnitRecipe>
<RecipeStep>
<RECIPE>
<RECIPE_DATA>
<RECIPE_GENERAL_DATA>
<RECIPE_NAME>
<PPID>user_data/RDM/BACKUP</PPID>
</RECIPE_NAME>
<GENERAL_DATA>
<CREATED_BY></CREATED_BY>
<CREATED_TIME>2020-05-16T16:13:49.879847+02:00</CREATED_TIME>
<LAST_MODIFIED_BY></LAST_MODIFIED_BY>
<LAST_MODIFIED_TIME>2020-08-12T09:16:07.409547+02:00</LAST_MODIFIED_TIME>
<STORAGE_MODIFICATION_NR>8</STORAGE_MODIFICATION_NR>
<COMMENT_ARRAY>
<elt>&lt;This Formatted Process Program was created from an exported recipe.&gt; 
</elt>
</COMMENT_ARRAY>
</GENERAL_DATA>
<SOFTREV>6.2.0.b</SOFTREV>
<LAST_EXPORTED_BY></LAST_EXPORTED_BY>
<LAST_EXPORTED_TIME>2020-08-12T09:16:07.409547+02:00</LAST_EXPORTED_TIME>
<EXPORTED_FROM_STORAGE>8</EXPORTED_FROM_STORAGE>
<EXPORT_MODIFICATION_NR>8</EXPORT_MODIFICATION_NR>
<CALIBRATION_STATE_ID>DEFAULT</CALIBRATION_STATE_ID>
</RECIPE_GENERAL_DATA>
</RECIPE_DATA>
</RECIPE>
</RecipeStep>
</UnitRecipe>
</RecipeCollection>
</ADEL:Definitions>
```

Code used:

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim FilePath As String
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
MaskId = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value

Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFileName = Dir(FilePath & "\" & MaskId & "*.xml")
        
If XMLFileName = "" Then
   MsgBox "no file found"
Else
End If
        
Debug.Print XMLFileName = ""
oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)

MsgBox oXMLFile.validateOnParse
        
Set MaskNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/ADEL:Definitions/RecipeCollection/UnitRecipe/RecipeStep/RECIPE/RECIPE_DATA/RECIPE_GENERAL_DATA/SOFTREV/text()")
'Below is working for the other XML file
'Set MaskNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/ADEL:Report/Input/LotSettings/LotType/text()")

                
MsgBox MaskNodes(i).NodeValue
```

Comment: Theese images are not as helpful as actual sample of both working and non-working XML embedded in post (not [screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451)). Also, what is `i`? Try removing `text()`.

Comment: @Parfait I added the code of the XML files

Comment: Is the missing `<` character in `<CREATED_BY>/CREATED_BY>` a typo here or is it missing in the original file?

Comment: Closing tag for the root element also looks wrong `</ADELrap:Definitions>`

Comment: I deleted some info in the XML files because of sensitive content

Comment: `<SOFTREV>` (actual parent: `<RECIPE_GENERAL_DATA>`) is a next sibling to `<GENERAL_DATA>` but no ChildNode to it :-)

Comment: The correct closing nodes need `</RECIPE_DATA>` inserted between ...`</RECIPE_GENERAL_DATA>`
**</RECIPE_DATA>** `</RECIPE>`...

Comment: I changed the XML codes to working ones now, there were a few typos inside. At least I can open them in my XML reader.

Comment: ... are there remaining issues or did this solve your problem? @Wesley

Comment: When I run the code, it gives me an error on the 'msgbox' line. "object variable or with block not set" Also when I look in the locals view, the XML appear empty... I don`t think it is reading the file anyway I can check that first besides the fact of seeing the locals?

Comment: You can check for parsing errors on loading the XML  - look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762791(v=vs.85) for example

Comment: @TimWilliams, I added the `MsgBox oXMLFile.validateOnParse` in my code, you can see my edit. It returns `true` so the XML file is loaded properly?

Comment: You should check the `parseError` property

Comment: @Wesley - You can find a parseError routine at [Object variable or with block not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622752/object-variable-with-or-with-block-not-set/46623671#46623671)

Comment: Hmm I found what was wrong, I was loading the filename only without path. stupid mistake. Thanks for the support anyway. The ParseErrors is really helpfull and I added into the code in case other users will run into an issue