# Block variable not set Excel

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am getting error

> rum time error 91 block variable not set

with below code when trying to run in vba excel.. I checked references not sure what I will be missing here
My Code is as follow This was working prior not sure what changed here later :(

```
Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Dim XMLFileAddress As String
Dim oDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim fSuccess As Boolean
Dim oRSS_version As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim oChannel As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim oIRN As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Set oDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
fSuccess = oDoc.LoadXML(MyRequest.responseText)
If NotfSuccess Then
    errormg = "Could Not Download XML"
    GoTo ExitHere
End If
oDoc.async = False
oDoc.validateOnParse = False
 errormg = ""
Set oRSS_version = oDoc.DocumentElement
```

Comment: Edit question to include code.

Comment: Please copy more of your code (complete example). I am getting "The method cannot be called unti the Send method has beencalled" on line "fSuccess = oDoc.LoadXML(MyRequest.responseText)"

Comment: A related post [Object variable with or wit block not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622752/object-variable-with-or-with-block-not-set/46623671#46623671) including a parse error routine might give you some ideas, e.g.: are all variables declared correctly? Is XML not wellformed or does it include special entities? - btw use the current MSXML2 version 6.0 declaring `Dim oDoc As  MSXML2.DOMDocument60` and setting to memory via `Set oDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60` :-)