# Ignore content within an XML node when loading

Tags: xml, vba, xslt

I'm working with Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0 within vbscript in a program called Diadem by National Instruments. I think treating this as VBA is acceptable.

I'm trying load an XML document created by a 3rd party software.  Within one of the nodes, the 3rd party software creates text that is not valid for XML and causes an error on Load.

So, when I use the load method of Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0 I want to ignore any text within tags `<CALC_FUNC>` and `</CALC_FUNC>`

Is there any way to do this without manipulating the text strings directly?

Comment: Always helps to show the code you're using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**A)** If your concern is just to change existing node (contents) -- in wellformed xml documents -- you might profit from **XSLT** (describing a special purpose & platform independant language transforming xml) via an adapted *identity transform*.

A pure **identity transform** uses a push processing style sheet reproducing the xml content by a hierarchical traversal of the entire xml. -
Adding, however a special-case template to the
stylesheet grants the most specific template the *highest priority*.

If such a special template refers e.g. to `<CALC_FUNC>`, this allows to change the original content input by any wanted modification.

- If you just want your single element **removed**, just do nothing therein,
  neither a copy, nor something else - just show it, that suffices:

```
    <xsl:template match="CALC_FUNC"/>
```

**Save a xls style sheet `style.xsl` into sub directory `\xml` of calling worksheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CALC_FUNC"/><!-- Removes all CALC_FUNC elements -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- If you want the node **text** *deleted*, not the surrounding node names, change the above template and enter pure text within the template container:

```
  <xsl:template match="CALC_FUNC">
      <CALC_FUNC/>
  </xsl:template>
```

**Simple example call in VBA executing the transformation**

This gives only a basic example *(of early bound xml loads)* applying the `TransformNodeToObject` method to the data xml.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExampleCall()
    'Early bound loads
    'data
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.Load ThisWorkbook.Path & "\xml\data.xml"   ' << change file path as needed

    'xsl source (style sheet)
    Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xslDoc.Load ThisWorkbook.Path & "\xml\style.xsl"  ' << style sheet

   'transform & save
   Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
   xmlDoc.TransformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
   newDoc.Save ThisWorkbook.Path & "\xml\output.xml"

   'Debug.Print newDoc.XML         ' optional display in VB Editor's immediate window

End Sub
```

---

**B) Direct content manipulation via XML methods** //Edit as of 11/6 due to comment

> *Is there any way to do this without manipulating the text strings directly?*

The answer is simply **no, you can't**, if the xml document isn't well-formed being a pre-condition to further
XML manipulations. As michael.hor257k mentioned, *"trying to remove the offending text using XSLT will fail, because XSLT will not process an input that isn't a well-formed XML document."*.

- Though an invalid xml can't be processed, you can locate the errors.

**What to do?**

If *the 3rd party software creates text that is* **not valid** *for XML* this
will inevitably cause an error on `Load`. Nevertheless you can profit from loading as function call and get valuable information as starting point:

```
    If xmlDoc.Load(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\xml\data.xml") Then 
        ' some action as loaded successfully (e.g. Transform)
    Else
    ' analyze error as loading failed
    Dim ErrText as String
    ' Obtain the ParseError object
    Dim xPE As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError
    Set xPE = xmlDoc.ParseError
    With xPE
            ErrText = _
            "Error #: " & .ErrorCode & ": " & xPE.reason & _
            "Line #: " & .Line & vbCrLf & _
            "Line Position: " & .Linepos & vbCrLf & _
            "Position In File: " & .Filepos & vbCrLf & _
            "Source Text: " & .SrcText & vbCrLf & _
            "Document URL: " & .Url
        End With

        Debug.Print ErrText
    Stop
    End If
```

This returns not only a boolean value regarding the loading success, but enables you to further
analyze error causes and *locate* line & file positions where the error occurs (c.f.[IXMLDOMParseError Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms767720(v=vs.85))),
possibly step by step. The `srcText` member returns even the full text of the line containing the error as read-only info. A *frequent* cause offending valid xml are *special entities* like e.g. single Ampersands or  conflicting with xml requirements.

So you are in the position to plan your file recovery by direct file string manipulations (there are number of examples here at SO).

Comment: I get the impression that OP is dealing with an XML input that contains invalid text. If so, trying to remove the offending text using XSLT will fail, because XSLT will not process an input that isn't a well-formed XML document.

Comment: Thx for commenting. I may be wrong, but as far as the cited input of textual child elements within "tags <CALC_FUNC> and </CALC_FUNC>" is concerned I don't see that this isn't a well-formed XML node. @michael.hor257k

Comment: If there should be offending text in the start xml, the following link might give some help identifying it: [Object variable not set: XML doesn't load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622752/object-variable-with-or-with-block-not-set/46623671#46623671)

Comment: I don't see any "cited input".

Comment: @michael.hor257k Please accept my excuses having missed the sentence *.. creates text that is not valid for XML* in OP; will edit my answer. Of course this will fail already when loading. Thanks again :-;